# How to hot reload a Maven project with multiple modules

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, war

I have inherited a maven project that has the following structure:

```
-parent
-module_A
-module_B
```

here is a piece of the pom.xml of the parent as well:

```
    <modules>
        <module>../module_A</module>
        <module>../module_B</module>
    </modules>
```

module_A and B also have their own pom.xml files. All three have many dependencies. One of the dependencies for module_B, is module_A.

Currently I am able to build the project by changing my directory to the parent, and running `mvn clean install`. This causes the parent to build the two module's JAR files, and then produces a WAR file in module_B. The project is then manually deployed on a local Apache Tomcat server.

The problem I am having, is I primarily am making changes in module_B, and everytime I make a change and want to see it, I need to rebuild the entire project from the parent as described above, and it takes about 10 minutes. This is not sustainable, and I have been trying to figure out a way to hot reload the application as I make changes.

What I have tried so far, is loading the project into the Eclipse IDE, adding the correct server, and then right-clicking module_B and selecting the option to run it on the server. However this simply returns a message `the selection cannot be run on any server`. I know this isn't a server config issue because I can start the empty server and it runs without a problem.

I don't know what else to try. I am sure there is a solution to this, there is no way people have developed this large application I am working on by waiting 10 minutes every time they wanted to log something to the console. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: What did you mean by _"loading the project into the Eclipse IDE"_? Did you use _File > Open Projects from File System..._ or did you choose another way? Did you import all three as separate projects into Eclipse?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining more clearly. I used File > Open Projects from File System. I imported them all as a single project.

Comment: A single project will not work for multiple Maven modules. If `module_A` and `module_B` are Java applications or frameworks, the have to be separate projects in Eclipse, each with its own Java Build Path.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I was able to get the project running by adding `module_A.jar` to the `module_B` Java Build Path via the User Library. I had to also make some other modifications but eventually things ended up working out. Thanks again!